# "Auto resize VM with windows" greyed out since Graphics type 'vnc' does not support auto resize in Redhat

Tags: windows-10, resolution, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kvm, aspect-ratio

[image]

As per redhat spice is deprecated since RHEL 8.3 ( https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5414901 ) so i cannot use spice.It gives me errors when i try to use spice instead of vnc

[image]

Host : Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.0 (Plow)

guest : Windows 10 Pro

[image]

Is there anyway i can make changes so that the vm does not look like this with black borders around in full screen mode.I want to adjust the guest window to full screen without the black borders.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using VNC as Video method in virt-manager, but you should use QXL and the Spice Guest Tools

To install the QXL Drivers, just go to the [virtio-win-guest-tools-installer github repo](https://github.com/virtio-win/virtio-win-pkg-scripts/blob/master/README.md#downloads=)

### If your VM doesn't have internet access

Go to the github webpage and choose "Latest virtio-win ISO", then in virt-manager, go into your VM, and in the hardware details, go and click Add Hardware, then select Storage and leave this parameters like this:

- Device Type: CDROM Device
- Bus Type: SATA

Then select and search for the `virtio-win.iso` file you just downloaded, select it and add it to the VM.
Now you should start the Windows VM, go to the Device Manager > Display adapters and select the first one, do right click on it and select "Update driver", then select "Browse my computer for drivers", click on browse, select the CD Drive with the name of `virtio-win`, select OK and then just click Next. The driver QXL now should be installed.

### If your VM has internet access

You can click on the "Latest virtio-win-guest-tools.exe" option, which download the .exe file with the necessary drivers automatically (Display, internet drivers, missing PCI drivers and others). Then just install the .exe and ready to go.

## Spice guest tools

For installing this, go to the [windows binaries section of spice space](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html#windows-binaries) in the VM and select the first one which it says:

- `Windows guest tools - spice-guest-tools`

Download it and install it, now the "Auto resize VM with windows" should be available :)

Comment: Guessing you didn't read original question too deeply. SPICE has been deprecated in RHEL.